# {{ root_url }} in Octopress is blank

Tags: ruby, jekyll, octopress

The documentation for Octopress refers to `{{ root_url }}` in various points, but this value appears to be blank whenever it is used in my site.

I tried to research its purpose by looking for where it is defined in the code and cannot find it.

Has it been deprecated?
Is it the same as `{{ site.root }}`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is basically the same as `{{ site.root }}`.

For me, it is defined in my default layout:

```
{% capture root_url %}{{ site.root | strip_slash }}{% endcapture %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configuration to set it up:

Read about it in here:
http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/subdir/

```
# Set the root project to the desired path
rake set_root_dir[your/path]

# To go back to publishing to the document root
rake set_root_dir[/]
```